# AppleScript and Growl: How to choose the display style?

Tags: applescript, notifications, formatting, growl

I'm using AppleScript and calling Growl notifications and I notice that it ignores my choice of using Bezel as my system default style. It only changes if I manually change it in Growl's preferences.
How can I choose a style through AppleScript?
I ask this because different styles would be better for different notifications type.

Answer (score 1):

Each Applescript you use Growl with registers itself as a different *application* with Growl.

After the first time you use a script, you can go to Growl's settings. Look for the application name you registered the script as. (This is configurable in the `register as application "Application Name"` line when scripting Growl.)

Once you've used the script once, it should show up in Growl's settings. In there you can customize the display location and style specifically for that script, or as Growl calls it, that "application".

If you need more info about using Growl with Applescript, I have a blog post [here](http://vickash.com/2012/01/02/a-simpler-way-to-use-growl-with-applescript/), which explains how it works and provides a pre-built Applescript handler that you can drop into your scripts and call with a single line of code.

Comment: Just realized I didn't read your question properly and you already tried what's in my answer. AFAIK, Growl doesn't make the notification style and location settable via Applescript, just the app icon.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I asked it because sometimes I want the notifications to be really obstructive.

Comment: If you only need a few different styles, a kind of hack-ish workaround would be to script the registration of a bunch of different "applications", with names like "Top Left Crystal", "Bottom Right Bezel", corresponding with the display location and style.

Then, adjust the settings in Growl so they work like their names say they should. From there, whenever you send a notification from a script, don't use the script's name as the application name, but one of these instead. Basically you'd be encoding the location and style data into the application name.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that I can define a style inside Growl preferences panel for each "status" registered in the script like:

`notify with name "Mounting Notification"

notify with name "Already Mounted"`

Comment: Oh yeah. If you go over into the notifications tab it's there. That's still a bit hack-ish, but a cleaner way to do it at least.